# How to sort a column in dataset VB.NET having multiple sort conditions

Tags: vb.net, sorting, dataset, defaultview, columnsorting

I have a dataset in which there is a column contains various string type values like below:

Aircraft
Crime
Package Total
Apartments
DIC - Personnel

Now the requirement is that after applying sorting logic on this colum if there is a "Package Total"  value in it then it must come at the top position on the Dataset and after that all other values should be in alphabatically sorted order like below:

Package Total
Aircraft
Apartments
Crime
DIC - Personnel

We have used in Database below logic which is working fine but can't figure it out how to do it on Dataset VB.net from Fronend side:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN UseCarrierAllocation = 0 THEN 
    CASE WHEN InvoiceItemLevel LIKE 'Package Total%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 
    END 
END, InvoiceItemLevel ASC
```

Any reply/idea will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
    DataView dv = sDataSet.Tables("Table1").DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "column1";
```

Comment: Thnaks for you reply but it won't work... as it requires conditional sorting. your suggestion will work only for single condition sort.

Comment: Can you please give an example/sample of how to do looping/for-each in this scerario. I have this dataset table with various columns and one of the column is "InvoiceItemLevel" which i have mentioned with various values. So i need to sort that dataset table using multiple condition like i have said i need package line first then all in alphabetical order.

Comment: Use ToTable.  Example:  For Each myRow As DataRow In dv.ToTable.Rows

Answer (score 0):

```
YourDatasourceName.YourDatasetName.DefaultView.Sort = "YourColumnName"

YourDataTableName = YourDatasourceName.YourDatasetName.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "YourColumnName")
```

Comment: Describe the code that would help much better than just a piece of code